# How to merge multiple objects based on dynamic data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

variable array has multiple objects so i want to merge objects based on repeated id and other values will assign into offer objects how to do that ?.. Thanks in advance

```
var array = [
   {
      id:1,
      shopname:'star salon',
      offid: 12,
      offname:'100% discount'
   },
   {
      id:1,
      shopname:'star salon',
      offid: 16,
      offname:'Billing Value discount'
   },
   {
      id:3,
      shopname:'trend beauty',
      offid: 19,
      offname:'Percentage Offer'
   }

 ]
```

And finally out put is given below:

```
  var result = [
  {
    id:1,
    shopname:'star salon',
    offer : [
      {
        offid: 12,
        offname:'100% discount'
      },
      {
        offid: 16,
        offname:'Billing Value discount'
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    id:3,
    shopname:'trend beauty',
    offer : [
       {
          offid: 19,
          offname:'Percentage Offer'
       }
    ]
  }

 ]
```

Comment: group by id, or name?

Comment: group by id and  shopname

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you immediately started off with an array of offers (even if only one). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code, which collects the items in a plain object, keyed by id, and then extracts the values from it:

```js
var array = [{id:1,shopname:'star salon',offid: 12,offname:'100% discount'},{id:1,shopname:'star salon',offid: 16,offname:'Billing Value discount'},{id:3,shopname:'trend beauty',offid: 19,offname:'Percentage Offer'}];

var result = Object.values(array.reduce( (acc, {id, shopname, offid, offname}) => {
    acc[id] = acc[id] || { id, shopname, offer: [] };
    acc[id].offer.push({ offid, offname });
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```